# WPF Media Player natural duration

Tags: c#, wpf, media-player

If I use:

```
string Text = mediaPlayer.NaturalDuration.ToString();
```

I get everytime "automatic" as text. Is it the correct way to get media duration? What I do incorrect? Do you know any diferent solution? I want to get text in min:seconds pattern ideally.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the `NaturalDuration` has a value of automatic, then the `MediaOpened` event has not been raised.

Once the event is raised, you can get the duration like:

```
string Text = mediaPlayer.NaturalDuration.TimeSpan.ToString(@"mm\:ss");
```

Comment: Than you, but just for the sake of interest do you know about any possible solution without MediaOpened event ussage? If I understand when I write mediaPlayer.Open(something), mediaPlayer.Play() and mediaPlayer.NaturalDuration in the row I get "Automatic" because player hasn't opened all the media yet? Am I right?

Answer (score 0):

use listeners to do the rest of code when media is opened

```
mediaPlayer.Open(new Uri(openFileDialog.FileName));
mediaPlayer.MediaOpened += MediaPlayer_MediaOpened;
mediaPlayer.MediaEnded += MediaPlayer_MediaEnded;
```